# AT&T to inline asm in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, inline-assembly, att, dll-injection

I'm trying to convert assembly written in AT&T syntax from a DevC++ project to inline assembly in Visual Studio.

This is the AT&T I'm trying to convert:

```
void Painter::drawRectangle(int surface, int x, int y, int width, int height, int red, int green, int blue) {
    asm("mov %0, %%eax":: "r" (0x004EAA90));
    asm("call *%eax");
    asm("mov %eax, %ecx");
    asm("mov (%ecx), %eax");
    asm("push %0":: "m" (blue));
    asm("push %0":: "m" (green));
    asm("push %0":: "m" (red));
    asm("push %0":: "m" (height));
    asm("push %0":: "m" (width));
    asm("push %0":: "m" (y));
    asm("push %0":: "m" (x));
    asm("push %0":: "m" (surface));
    asm("call *0x14(%eax)");
}
```

what i've done so far:

```
void _drawrectangle(int surface, int x, int y, int width, int height, int red, int green, int blue)
{    
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 0x004eaa90
        call dword ptr [eax]
        mov ecx, eax
        mov eax, [ecx]
        push blue
        push green
        push red
        push height
        push width
        push y
        push x
        push surface
        call dword ptr [eax + 0x14]
    }
}
```

I'm writing this in my DLL, which I've already injected into the game. The game crashes on opening. And I've already hooked another drawing function in C++, which worked.

Hopefully you can help me/guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: `mov eax, ecx` should probably be `mov eax, [ecx]`. Why do you flip the order that parameters are pushed?

Comment: In any case that looks like just two function calls, why do you need assembly for it?

Comment: You shouldn't be using inline assembly for either. Just use plain assembly, then you don't need to worry about the code in your first example breaking because you've used inline assembly code is wrong. Or like Jester said, plain C++ will also work.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Ops, forgot to switch the order back after testing.

Comment: @RossRidge how can I use plain assembly in visual studio?

Comment: @Jester I don't have the memory address of the function

Comment: The memory address of the function is in your assembly code.

Comment: @RossRidge I can only see the first. What about this one:  call dword ptr [eax + 0x14]?

Comment: The call to the first obtains the second indirectly.

Comment: @RossRidge how would you write this in C++? Can you do some pseudo-code or something? Thank you for helping

Comment: the original code is already broken unless you get lucky and compile with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` because you manipulate the stack pointer without telling the compiler.

Comment: Make sure you go and replace the AT&T version with Ross's answer, too, because it's hilariously badly broken.  If it works, it's only with optimization disabled.  Like @fuz said, it might work if args args are referenced relative to EBP, but it also clobbers EAX without telling the compiler.  As well as not restoring ESP when its done.  And assuming that the compiler won't modify registers in between `asm` statements.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more info if you have any more asm written this badly.

Comment: @PeterCordes The function where the Painter::drawRectangle() is called from has SAVE_STACK, SAVE REGISTERS before it and, LOAD STACK, LOAD REGISTERS after the call. And the original AT&T code draws the rectangle ingame.

Comment: Like Fuz said, the function itself will be miscompiled with optimization enabled.  `-fomit-frame-pointer` is on by default with optimization enabled, so `"m"(red)` will compile to something like `push 24(%esp)`, which will break because you modify `%esp` without telling the compiler in earlier `asm` statements.  Everything about this code is terrible and wrong (and I say this as an expert in using GNU C inline asm; I wrote the tag wiki I linked earlier, and several of the SO answers it links to).  If `SAVE_STACK` is written anything like this, I'm not optimistic.

Comment: @PeterCordes
`#define SAVE_STACK      \
 asm(".intel_syntax noprefix");  \
 asm("mov _g_lastEsp, esp");  \
 asm("mov _g_lastEbp, ebp");  \
 asm(".att_syntax noprefix")`

Comment: @PeterCordes btw, thanks for the inline-assembly link, more like it or how to look at asm code and figure out how it should be in c++ would be great. Like ross managed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you could write your function in C++ without the use of inline assembly:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
/* For GCC and clang */
#undef __thiscall
#define __thiscall __attribute__((thiscall))
#endif

struct some_interface {
    virtual void _unknown_0() = 0;
    virtual void _unknown_4() = 0;
    virtual void _unknown_8() = 0;
    virtual void _unknown_C() = 0;
    virtual void _unknown_10() = 0;
    virtual void __thiscall drawRectangle(int surface, int x, int y,
                          int width, int height,
                          int red, int green, int blue) = 0;
};

const auto get_interface = (some_interface *(*)()) 0x4EAA90;

void 
drawRectangle(int surface, int x, int y, int width, int height,
          int red, int green, int blue) {
    get_interface()->drawRectangle(surface, x, y, width, height,
                       red, green, blue);
}
```

The code you're trying to translate first calls a function that returns a pointer to some class object with at least 6 virtual methods defined.  It then calls the 6th virtual method of that object.  The `some_interface` struct minimally recreates that class so the 6th virtual method can be called.  The `get_interface` constant is a function pointer that points to the function located at 0x4EAA90 and in C++ function pointers can be used just like a function.

The above code [generates the following assembly in GCC 8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/GOF1UG):

```
drawRectangle(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int):
        subl    $12, %esp
        movl    $5155472, %eax
        call    *%eax
        movl    (%eax), %edx
        movl    %eax, %ecx
        pushl   44(%esp)
        pushl   44(%esp)
        pushl   44(%esp)
        pushl   44(%esp)
        pushl   44(%esp)
        pushl   44(%esp)
        pushl   44(%esp)
        pushl   44(%esp)
        call    *20(%edx)
        addl    $12, %esp
        ret
```

and the [following assembly with Visual C++ 2017](https://godbolt.org/z/XadJpj):

```
void drawRectangle(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int) PROC                  ; drawRectangle, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 5155472                          ; 004eaa90H
        call    eax
        push    DWORD PTR _blue$[esp-4]
        mov     ecx, eax
        push    DWORD PTR _green$[esp]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [eax]
        push    DWORD PTR _red$[esp+4]
        push    DWORD PTR _height$[esp+8]
        push    DWORD PTR _width$[esp+12]
        push    DWORD PTR _y$[esp+16]
        push    DWORD PTR _x$[esp+20]
        push    DWORD PTR _surface$[esp+24]
        call    DWORD PTR [edx+20]
        ret     0
void drawRectangle(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int) ENDP                  ; drawRectangle
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: Could you also please elaborate on how you saw that it was at least 6 virtual functions in the interface? I also don't get how it after 0-4-8-C counts to 10

Comment: @SornNaserZupanicMaksumic In hexadecimal C + 4 = 10.

Comment: How did you know it was functions in the object and not variables?

Comment: Also, if you have time and even though it's not recommended: how would you write it in inline assembly? Including saving and loading the registers. I've played around with the VS 2017 code produced from godbolt, but no luck. Just curious.

Comment: And lastly, can you guide me to a place where I can read more about how you figured all this out?

Comment: What is this doing : (some_interface *(*)()) 0x4EAA90? I don't get why you can't do: some_interface* get_interface = (some_interface *) 0x4EAA90;

Comment: 1) The fact the second functional called uses the __thiscall calling convention and is passed the return value of the first function call in ECX (the `this` pointer) means that return value is a pointer to a class object. 2) Don't use inline assembly, especially not in Visual Studio. 3) I don't know of any place where you can read more about this 4) It's a cast that converts the integer into a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to `some_interface`. It's not the same thing as a pointer to `some_interface`.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Just curious, is there a way to access the drawRectangle function directly without having to go through the struct? Or at least shorten the path to get to it?